# How can I have a map between types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have several types as input argument and each of them there is a paired return type. I'd like to find a way to remap the input types into a corresponding return type.

I tried this but I don't know how to set a right return value expression:

```
class P1 {
   i = 0; // to make the class be different from other...
}

class P2 {
   s = '';  // to make the class be different from other...
}

class R1 {
  public foo() {}
}

class R2 {
  public bar() {}
}

type Input = P1 | P2;

function remap<T extends Input>(value: T) : R1 | R2 /* or what should I put here??? */ {
    if (value instanceof P1) {
        return new R1;
    }
    else {
        return new R2;
    }
}

const v = remap(new P1);
/*
Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'R1 | R2'.
  Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'R2'.
*/
v.foo() // I want to v to be auto inferred as R1 instead of R1 | R2
```

Comment: ① Your `P1` and `P2` are [empty classes and thus equivalent to each other](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely).  If they aren't empty in your actual code, could you add some structure to distinguish them here?  Otherwise we'll be chasing down issues that aren't relevant.  ② Once you do that, does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mZyv4N) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz The `T extends P1 ? R1 : R2` you mentioned in the link made a right result. However, if I have a few types to remap should I have to wrote them all into one multi-levels-nested extends expression?

Comment: A single nested conditional type will work, but if you have a lot of types then you can structure it differently.  But I'd want to see a [mre] in the question before venturing any further.  As it stands now it looks like you have a lot of answers doing similar things so I won't post my own

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do it like this: https://tsplay.dev/Ndy8Ym

```
type Mappings = [
  [P1, R1],
  [P2, R2],
]
type Constructor<T> = new (...a: never[]) => T

const map = new Map<Constructor<Mappings[number][0]>, Constructor<Mappings[number][1]>>([
  [P1, R1],
  [P2, R2],
])

function remap<T extends Mappings[number][0]>(value: T): Extract<Mappings[number], [T, any]>[1] {
  for (let [p, r] of map.entries()) {
    if (value instanceof p) return new r();
  }
  throw new Error('Missing mapping', { cause: value })
}

const v = remap(new P1);
//    ^?
// const v: R1
```

---

Type remapping works like this:

- You have `type A = [1, 2] | [3, 4]`
- You `type B = Extract<A, [1, any]>` - this picks only those types where `t[0]` extends `1`
- You take the second element you are looking for with `type C = B[1]`

If you want a one-liner you may write it as

```
type TMap = [1, 2] | ['foo', 'bar'] | [{a:1}, {b:2}]
type GetMapped<Search, Pairs extends [unknown, unknown]> = 
| Pairs extends [Search, infer Result] ? Result : never;

type X = GetMapped<1, TMap>
//   ^?
// type X = 2
```

Comment: Actually all I need is the static type inferring so I tried this `type Remap<T> = T extends Mappings[number][0] ? Extract<Mappings[number], [T, any]>[1] : any` from your answer.
But I don't understand much about this expression could you add some more details?

Comment: @jayatubi updated

Comment: Avoid `any`, though. Prefer `unknown` in covariant position and `never` in contravariant position.

Answer (score 1):

Just set R1 | R2 or add another type like Input. I mean that works and the type will be correct. You could also use any which I would omit.

Or do this but it is unsafe as if you have not any guarding making sure that v is really R1.

```js
class P1 {}
class P2 {}
class R1 {
  public foo() {
    console.log("foo");
  }
}
class R2 {
  public bar() {
    console.log("bar");
  }
}

type Input = P1 | P2;

function remap<T extends Input>(value: T): T extends P1 ? R1 : R2 {
    if (value instanceof P1) {
        return new R1 as T extends P1 ? R1 : R2;
    }
    else {
        return new R2 as T extends P1 ? R1 : R2;
    }
}

const v = remap(new P1);
v.foo()
```

Now using P2 leads to an error as foo is not defined on that class.

Comment: Sorry for I didn't make my question clearly. What I want is to statically check the type of the return value so I could directy use the result as a concrete type without casting.

Comment: I mean if you do that and don't know the type you would need to check the instance in any way to be safe. But there is an more or less unsafe solution. I'll post it. Normally you would use some kind of pattern here fascade or simple inheritance with polymorphism...

Comment: "Now using P2 leads to an error as foo is not defined on that class." Have you tried that?  You will run into an issue with `const v = remap(new P2); v.bar(); v.foo();` because the `P1` and `P2` classes are empty.  Both OP and you should probably add structure to `P1` and `P2` (see my comment on the question above) or else this is not possible

Comment: Yep I added structure and it still works. I mean as I stated you are not guarding the call of v.foo or v.bar it may run into issues. And clearly calling both on v can't be possible.

Comment: "Now using P2 leads to an error as foo is not defined on that class." is not true for the code you've shown here.  If you do not add structure, then it will not work.  Just take your code, plug in `new P2` instead of `new P1`, and tell me what you see.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply declare the same function with multiple type signatures:

```typescript
function remap(value: P1): R1;
function remap(value: P2): R2;

function remap(value: P1|P2) {
    if (value instanceof P1) {
        return new R1;
    }
    else {
        return new R2;
    }
}
```

To declare just a type, without an actual function, you can use this syntax:

```typescript
type RemapFunc = {
    (_: P1): R1;
    (_: P2): R2;
};
```

Comment: Can I use this `RemapFunc` to make a `type Remap<T> = /*... some code to return mapped from T ... */`?

Comment: Doubtful, actually. <https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types> warns: “It is not possible to perform overload resolution based on a list of argument types.”